# sql insert id of row into a string in update statement

Tags: mysql

how do i do this in mysql 5.5? Was thinking concat but I think there's something simpler.

```
id  content
1
2

update posts set content='here is content ' + this.id
```

so that:

```
id content 
1  here is content 1
2  here is content 2
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you need:

```
update posts
    set content=CONCAT('here is content ', CAST(id as CHARACTER))
```

Here is a [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2c13/4) to a test on SQLFiddle.

Comment: @MichaelBuen Thanks! I know now that [it works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2c13/4)! Great tool!

Answer (score 0):

I guess:

```
update comment set comment=concat('here is a comment: ', id,' these are other things');
```